# Angular canActivate redirecting to login on browser refresh Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angular5

Angular 5 authentication app using angularfire2 and firebase. The app works fine navigating using in-app links. However, if  I hit the browser refresh, it redirects me back to the Login page. The allowed is always returning False even when is true because I made a successful Login with firebase.

AuthInfo

```
export class AuthInfo {  
    constructor(public $uid: string) {}

    isLoggedIn() {
        // console.log(this.$uid);
        return !!this.$uid;
    }
}
```

AuthService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
// tslint:disable-next-line:import-blacklist
import {Observable, Subject, BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AuthInfo } from '../security/auth-info' ;
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  static UNKNOWN_USER = new AuthInfo(null);
  authInfo$: BehaviorSubject<AuthInfo> = new BehaviorSubject<AuthInfo>(AuthService.UNKNOWN_USER);

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {}
    login(email, password): Observable<AuthInfo> {
        return this.fromFirebaseAuthPromise(this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password));
    }

    // signUp(email, password) {
    //  return this.fromFirebaseAuthPromise(this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password));
    // }

    fromFirebaseAuthPromise(promise): Observable<any> {
        const subject = new Subject<any>();
        promise
              .then(res => {
                    const authInfo = new AuthInfo(this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid);
                    this.authInfo$.next(authInfo);
                    subject.next(res);
                    subject.complete();
                    // console.log(res);
                },
                err => {
                    this.authInfo$.error(err);
                    subject.error(err);
                    subject.complete();
                });
        return subject.asObservable();
    }

    logout() {
        this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
        this.authInfo$.next(AuthService.UNKNOWN_USER);
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
    refresh() {
        const url = window.location.href;
    } 
}
```

AuthGuard

```
import {tap, take, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router} from '@angular/router';
// tslint:disable-next-line:import-blacklist
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../security/auth-service';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { auth } from 'firebase';
import { log } from '@firebase/database/dist/src/core/util/util';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    redirectUrl: string;
    currentURL= '';
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
        console.log(this.authService.authInfo$);

        return this.authService.authInfo$.pipe(
            map(authInfo => authInfo.isLoggedIn()),
            take(1),
            tap(allowed => {
                if  (!allowed) {
                    console.log(allowed);
                     this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                }
            }),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The `if  (!allowed)` is taking the null and undefined as false, how about filtering non boolean values before the `tap` ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun yes its coming always  null or false when i refresh the page , but i think its because firebase does not send the uid before authguard its executed , no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `authInfo$` is initialised with `UNKNOWN_USER` which will always make the first fired value not true, when reloading you take only the first value `take(1)` which is the default.

One solution is making the first value `null` and filter `null` values in the Observable used in the guard :

AuthService

```
...
new BehaviorSubject<AuthInfo>(null);
...
```

AuthGuard

```
...
return this.authService.authInfo$.pipe(
  filter(_ => _ !== null),
  map(authInfo => authInfo.isLoggedIn()),
  take(1),
...
```

This way only values that have meaning for the guard would be fired.

Comment: Thanks. It is a smart solution. But I wonder why you put map() in front of take(1)

Comment: The `map` and `take(1)` order doesn't matter, in the both cases `take(1)` will unsubscribe after the first not null value.